# How to get firebase key value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the below Firebase Database structure and I want to retrieve this value.. see below image... how to do it?

I was able to retrieve the CategoryName & Recipes using the below but unable to get their parent

```
//create reference for the fire base database
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
print(rootRef)
//get Category path
let childRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Bookmarks")
print(childRef)
let itemsRef = childRef.child(userID)
print(itemsRef)

//retrieve data from firebase database
itemsRef.observe(.value, with: {
    snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children
    {
        var recipes: String = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Recipes").value as !String
        var categoryName: String = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "CategoryName").value as !String
    }

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `key` inside the `for..in` loop, you can do the following:

```
  let key = child.key as String
  print(key)
```

Check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

To get the `key` from firebase you can try following in your code:

```
itemsRef.observe(.value, with: {
    snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children
    {
          if let alldata = child as? DataSnapshot{
         //key value
         guard let keyValue = alldata.key as? String else { return }
         print(keyValue)

         var recipes: String = alldata.childSnapshot(forPath: "Recipes").value as? String
        var categoryName: String = alldata.childSnapshot(forPath: "CategoryName").value as? String
        }
    }

})
```